# Different type deduction for a const int variable and a number

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

```
template<typename T>
void func(T&);

int x=0;
func(x); // OK, int&

const int cx=0;
func(cx); // OK, const int&

func(0); // invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'
```

But why doesn't the 'const int&' type get deduced in the third case? What is the rationale behind this type deduction rule?

After all, we can perfectly bind a number to const lvalue reference.

Comment: Are you asking why template type deduction rules are different than normal type deduction rules? If yes, you should probably clarify that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the type of `0` is `int`, not `const int`. (There are no cv-qualified prvalues of scalar type.) Since the deduction only takes into account the type, and not the value category, `T` must be deduced as `int` here just as it was in the case of `x`---*even though* that results in an attempt to perform an invalid reference binding.

(A *forwarding reference* `T&&` has special rules that take into account the argument's value category when deducing `T`. So passing in `x` and passing in `0` would deduce `T` differently. But for an ordinary reference `T&`, only the argument's type matters.)

Comment: OK, thank you. But what is the rationale behind defining the type of 0 to be 'int' instead of 'const int' then?

Comment: @beginpluses I think that is for backward compatibility with C - where the type of integer literals was decided as being `int` long before `const` even existed. Also, as I said, there are no cv-qualified prvalues of scalar type.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to imagine whats going wrong here if you understand that a reference is just a pointer with syntax. So if your method was:

```
template<typename T>
void func(T*);

int x=0;
func(&x); // OK, you can take the address of x

const int cx=0;
func(&cx); // OK, you can take the address of cx

func(&0); // Taking the address of 0 doesn't make sense.
```

Comment: No, that's not it. You can do the following just fine for example: `const int& i = 0;`. The actual reason is that templates use different deduction rules.